# Hiding an unordered list when it has no elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a problem that seems at first like a total no-brainer and an easy task.

I have a JavaScript plugin on my page that generates a Table Of Contents list to the sidebar of my Wordpress pages. My purpose is to hide the text widget element of the `#toc` when the  list within it has no elements. I'm trying to solve it using jQuery but no luck.

The HTML:

```
<div class="textwidget">
   <div id="toc">
     <ul></ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    if (!$('#toc').children('ul').has('li')) {
        $('#toc').parent().hide();
    }

});
```

My script should hide this specific `#toc`'s parent, because it has no child `<li>` elements, but it doesn't. Instead, when I remove the **!** from my if sentence, the script hides my list, as if it had something in it. It then also hides the lists that actually have elements in them. Am I totally missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#toc ul li').length < 1) {
        $('#toc').parent().hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#YourListID").hide();
var a = $("#YourListID li").length();
if (a  > 0 ) {
    $("#YourListID").show();
}
else {
    $("#YourListID").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following:

1) Give the UL an ID and check it's HTML. Ex:

```
var ulHtml = $("#myULElement").html();
if(ulHtml == ''){
    $('#toc').parent.hide();
}
```

2) Do the same as above but with a relative path, like:

```
var ulHtml = $("#toc ul").html();
//etc...
```

See if that works. If it does, we can elaborate on it further.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
if(!$('#toc').has('ul li').length) {
    $('#toc').closest('.textwidget').hide();
}
```

Working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6r8La/)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add `.length` to your testing statement.

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

```
if (!$('#toc').children('ul').has('li').length) {
    $('#toc').parent().hide();
}
```

});

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CQHCx/)

Source: http://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 0):

Use length to evaluate if there are `<li>` or not.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/YFP45/1/)**

```
<div class="textwidget">
   <div id="toc">
       <ul></ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

---

```
if ($('#toc ul li').length<1) {
        $('#toc').parent().hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

inside $(document).ready check for this

```
if($.trim($('#toc ul').html()).length == 0){
$('#toc').parent().hide();
}
```

as case may arise

```
<ul></ul>


 <ul>

   </ul>
```